# Cursor position changes on formatting to currency format by directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, format

Hello all,

I am using this currency format directive on the input element to format to currency while I type

```
        (function() {
var currencyFormatDir = function($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl)
                return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(a) {
                var abs = $filter(attrs.currencyFormat)(ctrl.$modelValue);
                return $filter(attrs.currencyFormat)(ctrl.$modelValue);
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber));
                if (plainNumber === 0) {
                    return "";
                }
                else {
                    return plainNumber;
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
angular.module('myApp').directive('currencyFormat', ['$filter', currencyFormatDir]);})();
```

But if I want to change the valve , For example: say I have the  figure 156 And I want to change it to 12,356
Then I would move my cursor to the right of the figure 1 and type 23
But if I did that here then I would end up with the number 12,563
This happens because the cursor shifts to the end . I dont know why this is happening , can someone help me to figure this out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a timeout that's reset every time a user types that will do the formatting after 1-2 secs?